# Como saber si un registro esta en mi base de datos PDO

Tags: php, pdo

soy nuevo programando , estoy consultando una base de datos con PDO. Pero me encuentro sin respuestas a la hora de saber si un registro se enceuntra o no en mi base de dato. Hasta ahora todo lo he podido hacer viendo bibliografias pero esta parte no me funciona. Les pongo el codigo de mi metodo, el cual es similar a tod lo que he venido haciendo pero no se pk razon aqui no me funciona.

```
 public function InsertarClientes($first_name, $last_name, $email, $password, $mobile, $address1, $address2)
    {
        $cnx = new ConexionDB();
        $cn = $cnx->getConexion();

        //INICIO verificando si existe este correo en la base de dato
        $res =  $cn->prepare("select count(*) from user_info where email=$email");
        $res->execute();
        $rows = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        $cantidad_de_resultados = $rows[0];

                    
              
        if ($cantidad_de_resultados > 0) {//aqui cuando deberia dar mayor q cero no lo esta haciendo
        //FINAL verificando si existe este correo en la base de dato

        return 3;//Ya existe un cleinte con ese correo en nuestra base de datos.

        }

        else {
            $res = $cn->prepare("Insert into user_info(first_name, last_name, email, password, mobile, 
            address1, address2) values('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$password', '$mobile', '$address1', '$address2')");

            $res->execute();

            //Quedandome con el id del ultimo registro insertado
            $ultimo_id_insertado = $cn->lastInsertId();

            if ($ultimo_id_insertado) {
                return 1;//EL cliente se insertó correctamente.
            } else {
                return 2;//No se pudo insertar el cliente.
            }
        }
    } I
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: es verdad, pero eso fue a la hora d escribirlo aca pero lo tengo bien en el proyecto , deja actualizarlo aca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se recomienda usar sentencias preparadas para prevenir [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php) (*pero no las estarías usando correctamente*) y para obtener el resultado del `count(*)` podes usar `fetchColumn`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
//INICIO verificando si existe este correo en la base de dato
$res =  $cn->prepare("select count(*) from products where email=?");
$res->execute([$email]);
$cantidad_de_resultados = $res->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Grande, un abrazo y un sldos!!!....